# Google Sheet: Exclude a row from counting based on value of another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I have a Google sheet as follows:

[image]

I am counting all "yes" in column B based on the formula `=COUNTIF(B2:B6,"Yes")`.
However, I would like to exclude row 5 based on the value "EXCLUDE" in column A.

How can I perform such filtering?

Answer (score 1):

you can try either:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"Yes",A2:A6,"<>"&"EXCLUDE")
```

OR

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(B:B,B:B="yes",A:A<>"EXCLUDE")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How this can be implemented in case I would like to use COUNTA instead of COUNTIF?

Comment: Sorry I didnt exactly get your query but anyways the second formula works with COUNTA. FILTER the data first and count the number of instances by wrapping the filter with counta function.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6="yes"; A2:A6<>"exclude")
```